# Getting git return values in shell script

Tags: git, bash, rebase

I'm writing a shell script that makes some git calls. In particular, I'm looking for a way to figure out if a git rebase call is successful or if there is a merge conflict. This is what I have so far.

```
returnStatus=$(git rebase master);
if [[ returnStatus == 1 ]]; then
    break;
else
    echo $branch; echo "rebased successfully";
fi
```

However, I think the first line isn't storing the return value, but the actual output of the rebase call. I need to know whether it was successful or not. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance! Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just this should do:

```
if git rebase master; then
    echo "$branch"
    echo "rebased successfully"
else
    break
fi
```

I don't know why you have a `break` there... are you in a loop? otherwise you probably mean `exit`...

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I'm in a loop

Answer (score 3):

`$?` contains the exit code of the last command. You can execute e.g.

```
git rebase ...
case $? in
    0) ... ;;
    1) ... ;;
    ...
esac
```

Comment: Adding a comment to this for those that fall upon it, `git rebase` will have exit code 0 if it has conflicts